# Does JavaFX provide a mechanism to check if a Stage is already open?

Tags: javafx-8

In my application I have created two separate launchers for window types.  Either the process is a Single Page Application (SPA) or a Multi Document Interface.

To ensure that these windows are managed correctly I have provided a launcher similar to the following:

```
public static void openSPA(String spaFXML, String windowTitle, String iconString, double x, double y) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent node = loader.load(SPALauncher.class.getClassLoader().getResource(spaFXML).openStream());
            Scene scene = new Scene(node);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(SPALauncher.class.getClassLoader().getResource("css/application.css").toExternalForm());

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            SPAControllerBase controller = (SPAControllerBase)loader.getController();

            controller.setScene(scene);
            controller.setPrimaryStage(stage);
            controller.buildAvailableLayoutMenu();
            stage.setTitle(windowTitle);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setX(x);
            stage.setY(y);

            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(iconString));
            stage.show();

            controller.initSPA();

        }catch(Exception e){
            //process the error
        }
    }
```

Without keeping a reference to the window that has been opened, is there a way to look for the stage in the JVM already?  Basically, if the user attempts to open the same window again, I would rather bring it into focus - not open it a second time.  Since the user may open the same stage in different contexts, I would want to look based on the title (which would be unique) and either open or bring forward.

I know I can keep references, but then I need to manage removing them as well, which I can do...  Just wondering if there was a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [StageHelper](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~kcr/openjfx-8u5-8u-sync/webrev/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/stage/StageHelper.java.html).getStages() (JavaFX 8 // Java 8 only), or define your own class extending Stage, and handling internal references by yourself.

If I were you, I'd rather go for the second option. Indeed, StageHelper is part of the "internal API" of JavaFX (not made public yet, and maybe it won't ever be).

*Regarding "handling internal references by yourself", some Singleton pattern may do the job. Then your launcher should test if the "CustomStage" (let's call it like this for the sake of the example) has already been instantiated (using a method from your CustomStage class).
NOTE: It should be the launcher's job to handle the references, but it seems like you don't want it to happen. So extending Stage is still an option.*

Comment: Thank you for that pointer.  I thought I'd need to manage it myself, but was hoping there was something built in.  But I don't want to use the internal API, since that could be broken at any time.

Comment: I agree with being pessimistic about internal API's ;-). Yet I did use the "Behavior" (from Skin) internal API for a long time in JavaFX 2, and a part of it ended being public in JavaFX 8... There is still a risk. It's up to you!

If you deliver your app with a bundled-JRE, there is no problem nor risk. Otherwise, be careful.

Comment: it seems like the problem with checking if a custom stage has already been instantiated using your own flags or internal references would be with indicating it has been removed, which needs to be indicated on all paths that remove or replace it. miss one, and there is an error. or is there some more robust method?